# Execution failure in Android app for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, build

I am new to android studio and am making a simple weather app. I wrote the code but I am still getting this error:

Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Here is my build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aseem.sunshine.app"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error and get the program to run?

Answer (score 0):

`com.android.support:appcompat-v7` library is being included twice in your project. Remove this line `compile files('android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')` from your `build.gradle`. Also you can remove this .jar from your project.